# How to receive incoming messages continously in angular 4/angular 2

Tags: angular, quickblox

I am trying to create a chat application for which I am using Quickblox Api to send and receive messages.But I am not getting a way to receive incoming messages correctly.

Right now,I am using the `setInterval` to retrieve messages after 5 seconds as follows.

```
this.setIntervalVariable = setInterval(() => {
    this.quickService.retreiveAllMessageByDialogId(this.currentDialogId).subscribe(
        res => {
            this.messageHistory = res.items;
        }
    )
}, 5000)
```

In service:

```
retreiveAllMessageByDialogId(Dialogid) {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('QB-Token', localStorage.getItem('QBToken'));
    return this._http.get("https://api.quickblox.com/chat/Message.json?chat_dialog_id=" + Dialogid, {headers: headers}).map(
        (res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

But what it does is that it calls Api after 5 seconds which increases network request unnecessarily. I want to know is there any alternate way this can be done. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: By default there is no server-to-client communication protocol. If Quickblox provides such api, you probably need to read their documentation.

Comment: You should read up on WebSockets. That's exactly what they are there for.

Answer (score 0):

I have also using some thing like this to get my notification frequantily. please try this

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.checkforNewUpdates();
  }   

 checkforNewUpdates() {
        Observable.interval(1000 * 60).takeUntil(this.onDestroy$).subscribe(x => {
          this.fetchData(url).subscribe(
            (data) => {
              console.log(data);
            })
        });
      }



    fetchData(url) {
        return this.http.get(url, {
          headers: // set header values
        }).map(
          (res) => res.json()
          )
      }
```

Comment: No,but thanks for answering.I dont want to call my Api after an interval but I only want to call it when I have received any message.

Comment: then plese use web sockets consupt

Answer (score 0):

WebSocket implementation is fine to meet this requirement.

Please go through [this](https://sparktutorials.github.io/2015/11/08/spark-websocket-chat.html) reference and try it, It may help you.

Thank you.